# Any Home Made Alternatives to using X-rays to identify ICs?

Tags: integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering, markings

I am on the hunt for several ICs by searching for the markings on them. But sometimes the markings are just too vague and I cannot really guarantee that the IC I found is the IC I am looking for. I know that some manufacturers place a logo or something equivalent on the die itself, and that it is possible to x-ray the package in order to see the bare die.

My question is, is there any home-made (preferably cheap) alternative to the x-ray method?

Comment: I take it you wouldn't be interested in some of the destructive techniques sometimes used, such as using a solvent to remove the encapsulation so it can be viewed under a microscope?

Comment: Simply remove the package and look at the die with an optical microscope. Hot acid spray is typically used, so it's not really suitable for literal home use, but for a small company it's possible.

Comment: [You could live dangerously](http://www.noah.org/science/x-ray/stong/).

Comment: Yeah, I came across the acid solution, but the piece of electronics that I want to "decipher" is expensive and I do want to reuse it...

Comment: Make friends with a friendly vetrinarian or maybe dentist.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess x-raying the parts will not tell you anything useful.

Comment: @MattYoung I don't think that's a very long limb. I've never seen resolution in an X-ray that would allow a chip ID to be resolved.

Comment: Yeah, I've X-Rayed a lot of ICs due to my line of work, and all you can see is the outline of the die, the shape of the lead frame, and occasionally the bond wires.  You won't be able to get any information from the dies like this.  Can you give us more information about the types of parts you might be looking at and what types of markings you're having trouble identifying?

Comment: @PeterK Inexpensive until you start paying for cancer treatment! A bit scary what the home handyman can construct if he's a bit smarter (braver? more stupid?) than average...

Comment: @markt Well, the 60s were a different time. I think my favourite part about that article is that one of the parts for the $20 x-ray machine is a vibrator from the spark coil of a Ford Model T.

Comment: So Acid it is? I came across this break down once (link below) and thought that they used some sort of imaging method to get pictures of the die out of the packing. Anyone can suggest any other possible solution to x-ray or acid?

http://www.chipworks.com/en/technical-competitive-analysis/resources/blog/inside-the-samsung-galaxy-s4/

Comment: Yes, those die shots will have been made by de-encapsulating it with acid. If the markings are merely faint rather than completely obliterated, there are techniques for making them more readable. Have you looked at the package under an optical microscope?